# Gluing metal to glass

Tags: adhesives, glass, metal

What type of glue is ideal for gluing metal to glass? The metal piece is fairly heavy. The glass sheet will lay vertical such that the adhesive will have to contend with gravity (weight of the metal piece).

There is also the possibility of mild handling of the metal piece, which the adhesive would also have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suitable adhesive for metal to glass can be found at the auto parts store. It is common to have inside rear view mirrors to fall from windshields.

The adhesive is a small tube similar to that in which toothpaste is sold and an activator swab or wipe.

One must be absolutely certain both surfaces are clean and perfectly flat. Follow the instructions on the packaging and you may get a solid bond.

I have, in the past, had great success with replacing fallen mirrors. The strength of this type of bond is quite impressive. I've also had a failure in two instances, possibly due to poor cleaning and/or poor retention while the adhesive cures.

If you can place the glass horizontal while the bond cures, all the better. Expect to use some form of tape for temporary security during the curing process.

Comment: keep in mind getting a bond with a polished surface is difficult, windshields are left unpolished in areas specifically for the glue, roughing up the surface to be glued with glass (fine sandpaper works) is a good idea, means more cleaning but you get a better hold. this applies ot a lesser extent to the metal.

Answer (score 1):

The best glue for glass and metal is UV activated. These [UV activated adhesives](https://www.panacol.com/kleber-produktgruppen/uv-kleber/) are often used for gluing glass to glass for aquariums. I have successfully used it to glue glass to metal, and I used a blacklight to do it. It’s fast and really strong. You don’t get a second chance.

In Europe you can get it from most glass-cutting or mirror-making craftspeople.